# iOS done button redirect to jsp

Tags: ios

Actually the requirement is we are enrolling a profile in iPod touch and when the profile is installed there is a Done button. When we click on the Done button we have to capture that event in java and redirect it to safari which is a jsp basically.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what you really need? Do you just need to redirect to safari when it is done? What does java or jsp have to do with it?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delay:here are the details that can help Hi I'm using iPod touch here are the steps:
1) After the Profile get installed i get a iOS screen with Done button on top right corner and after clicking done button it takes me to https://daw-uat.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/4/wo/dfQXOcmKtWV4SPtItkYLxM/0.3.3.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1
URL...
The URL opens up in safari browser...now how can i have a custom jsp or html page in place of the above default page that is currently displaying..

Comment: Actually i have no idea of how to handle the done button event since we are using java i thought if their is way to capture it using java and redirect it to jsp but please suggest if this is not the case..or you have a better way to do it. thanks

Comment: You keep saying Java. Are you talking about server-side code?

Comment: actually after clicking on Done button it goes to safari and opens https://daw-uat.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/4/wo/dfQXOcmKtWV4SPtItkYLxM/0.3.3.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.1  ---- this is a different server URL but not our application URL. its a different apple care URL. Is there a way i can redirect it app url ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. The functionality is built into the OS.

Perhaps someday Apple may elect to offer a redirect URL as part of a configuration profile, but I wouldn't hold your breath